# How to skip a number in a list in python?

Tags: python, selenium

I am filling a web form using selenium, where I need to put `cust_ID`, which is an 8 digit number.

After pressing the submit button, that form gives some information.

If the ID is invalid it is not giving any result. 
I have created a list:

`cust_ID =['00001001','00001002','00001003'.......]`

I created this list using for loop.

I want if the information exists for `id= 00001001` then the program should run-up to `00002000`

but if the information is not available for `id= 00001001` then iterator should jump to `id=00002001`

if the information is not found for `id= 00002001` then it should jump to `id=00003001`

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Show us the attempted code that you have written to solve this problem.

Comment: I dont have any idea how to do that ...